# SQL Command Returning Unexpected Results

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I am having issues with a sql procedure I wrote quite some time ago. The procedure is designed to generate a report that displays all missing records within our database.

For example, if ticket numbers 10, 11, and 13 have been used, then the procedure should return ticket number 12 on the report.

We manage each ticket book and issue them out accordingly when a person takes one. When the ticket book is issued, all 25 tickets in the book are created in the database, and when each individual ticket is entered into the database, the ticket is marked as used. This is how the procedure checks what tickets are used and not used.

This is the current procedure we are utilizing

```
create procedure FindMissingTickets
as
select TicketNum, TicketBookNum, UnitID, DateIssued, IssuedBy
from TicketBooks a
where a.Used='No'
and a.TicketNum < (select MAX(b.TicketNum)
            from TicketBooks b
            where b.Used='Yes'
            and b.UnitID=a.UnitID
            and b.BookType='Truck' or b.BookType='Work')
and a.BookType='Truck' or a.BookType='Work'
order by TicketNum desc
go
```

This is a quick example of how our database table is laid out:
[image]

So in theory, the ticket number 525 should be shown on this report. What is actually is happening is all of the records from ticket number 493 (the first ticket in the database) to 550 (the last ticket of this type) are shown in the report, even though that all of them except 525 are set the `Used`

I don't fully understand how this procedure could return any records that have the column `Used` set to `Yes`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `a.BookType in ('Truck', 'Work')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just missing parentheses, you need to place parentheses around the last part of your where clause:

```
and (a.BookType='Truck' or a.BookType='Work')
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I can't believe I missed that. I have been starting at this problem too long.

Comment: Anyways, it worked, and thank you very much! I can accept and answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: Happens too frequently to me, first thing I check!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to fix up your WHERE clause:

```
where a.Used='No'
and a.TicketNum < (select MAX(b.TicketNum)
            from TicketBooks b
            where b.Used='Yes'
            and b.UnitID=a.UnitID
            and b.BookType='Truck' or b.BookType='Work')
and (a.BookType='Truck' or a.BookType='Work')
```

You had:

```
WHERE A and B or C
```

I think you mean:

```
WHERE A and (B or C)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I seemed to overlook something quite simple!